# Shorten the process of finding the sum of positive number (users input 6 different intteger)

Tags: sum

I nedd to find the fatest and shortest way to calculate the sum of positive integer that the user input in.

```
    else if(num1<0 && num2 >0 && num3>0 && num4>0 && num5>0 &&num6>0){
        totalPositiveNumber =num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6;
        System.out.println("The sum of positive integer is: " + totalPositiveNumber);
    }
```

Comment: could you please format your code correctly `code should be between backticks`

Answer (score 0):

You can read the numbers and store them in an `array`. Later iterate over the array and sum only, when number is greater than `0`. Check below for sample code for reading input from `System.in` using `Scanner` class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sum {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    int array[] = new int[6];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++) {
      array[i] = read.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++) {
      if (array[i] > 0) {
        sum = sum + array[i];
      }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```

Comment: _italic_ Thank you for helping me